# How do you get real time updating in debug mode in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java

What I want to do is have my program I am making in real time update to reflect the changes made in the code. I believe this is done in debugger mode but whenever I turn on the debugger and run the code and make a change I do not see it change in the program running.

Am I doing something wrong that it is not working?

Comment: Here's a [link](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/eclipse-or-netbeans-hotswap-for-agile.html) on setting up hotswap for NetBeans and Eclipse.

Comment: I do not see the same options under my Compile > Build options as shown there. There is no drop down menu to select from those options.

Comment: Edit: I guess that option has changed and now it's just whether you want Compile on Save on or not. I have it checked and have `Apply Code changes after Save` on but it still does not update when I save and am in debug mode.

Comment: Which version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: 7.0.1. The link you gave is for a older version.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is called 'Compile on Save' or known by some has 'Hot swap'

Netbeans 8.2 **Tools->Options->Java->'Apply code changes after save'**

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave

> Using Compile on Save in Maven Projects
>
> **In 7.4 and later**
>
> Compile on Save has been reworked for 7.4. With Compile on Save turned
>   on, all Run/Debug related executions are performed by Maven itself,
>   only the Maven phases defined along with the goals are removed. Eg. if
>   your Run File mapping executes 'mvn package exec:exec' with Compile on
>   Save turned on the IDE will only execute 'mvn exec:exec'
>
> What are the advantages here?
>   • Everything is executed by Maven, just as it would on the cmd line.
>   • By skipping phase execution, the build becomes faster (but still a bit slower compared to the previous solution, there is one JVM startup for the maven build added)
>   **• It works not only for tests and main class execution, but any Run/Debug action mapping and any project packaging.**

For older IDE Versions Amir Afghani's answer seems good for Netbeans 7.0.1, from [here](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/eclipse-or-netbeans-hotswap-for-agile.html)

> From Netbeans preferences select "Miscelaneous | Java Debugger | General | Apply code changes after save"